# Android : access to Canvas without inheritance

Tags: android, layout, transparency

I want to draw in a view/layout, but I don't want to have to inherit from Layout, ( in order to have the onDispatch(Canvas canvas) method).
I want to draw bitmap over my main application, but without losing focus (so i cant run an activity to draw on screen).
I had a solution that was working but I had to inherit from LinearLayout and customize my onDispatch methode. Can I acces to the canvas of a view, I did not see any function that allows that.

Answer (score 1):

How about overriding `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` in view?